# React Jest Cannot find module '@emotion/styled' from 'node_modules/@mui/styled-engine/node/index.js'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, ts-jest

Hi I have a Storybook App and i'm trying to add some jest test:

This is my jest.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  roots: ["<rootDir>/src"],
  verbose: true,
  preset: "ts-jest",
  transform: {
    "^.+\\.(j|t)sx?$": "babel-jest",
    "^.+\\.(ts|tsx)?$": "ts-jest",
  },
  transformIgnorePatterns: [
    "/node_modules/(?![@autofiy/autofiyable|@autofiy/property]).+\\.js$",
    "/node_modules/(?![@autofiy/autofiyable|@autofiy/property]).+\\.ts$",
    "/node_modules/(?![@autofiy/autofiyable|@autofiy/property]).+\\.tsx$",
  ],
  modulePathIgnorePatterns: ["/cache", "/cypress", "/dist"],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    "\\.(css)$": "identity-obj-proxy",
  },
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ["<rootDir>/src/setupTests.ts"],
  testEnvironment: "jsdom",
  coverageReporters: ["json", "lcov", "text", "clover", "cobertura"],
  reporters: ["jest-junit"],
};
```

this is my component:

```
import { Box } from "@mui/material";
import React from "react";
import IGlobalComponent from "@app/storybook/src/interfaces/IglobalComponent";

export interface RectangleProps extends IGlobalComponent {
  color: string;
  width?: number;
  height?: string;
  name?: string;
  widthUnit?: string;
  heightUnit?: string;
}

export default function Rectangle(props: RectangleProps) {
  const {
    color,
    width = "3.77",
    height = "4.4",
    widthUnit = "%",
    heightUnit = "rem",
  } = props;
  return (
    <Box
      sx={{
        backgroundColor: color,
        width: width + widthUnit,
        height: height + heightUnit,
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

and there is my test file:

```
import React from "react";
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import Rectangle from "./Rectangle";

describe("Rectangle component", () => {
  test("should be render", () => {
    render(<Rectangle color="red" />);
  });
});
```

I run my test on this scripts:

```
"test": "cross-env BABEL_ENV=test jest --ci --reporters=default --reporters=jest-junit --coverage",
```

And I have a error: Cannot find module '@emotion/styled' from 'node_modules/@mui/styled-engine/node/index.js'

what is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try `npm install @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled` from the [MUI docs](https://mui.com/material-ui/getting-started/installation/).